# how do i use the text like in pe files?

Tags: pe, file-format

I extracted pe file from another pe file and I saved it.

I want it execute but when I saved file computer sees it like text file. Altough my actual file starting with "4d 5a" computer sees like text and converts it "34 64".
How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the text to bytes. You can use python 3 for that, in something like:

```
my_hexdata = "4d5a..."

bytes_ = bytes.fromhex(my_hexdata)

with open('output.exe', 'wb') as x:
    x.write(bytes_)
```

Answer (score 0):

use python,powershell,xxd -r, javascript
anything that you can script read a group of 2 char and make it one byte;

demo using binascii in python

```
:\>type asc2hex.py
import sys
import binascii
if(len(sys.argv)==2):
    inf = open(sys.argv[1],"rb");
    ouf = open("hex"+sys.argv[1] , "wb")
    dat= inf.read()
    inf.close()
    ouf.write(binascii.unhexlify(dat))
    ouf.close()
:\>type foo.bin
4d5a
:\>asc2hex.py foo.bin

:\>type hexfoo.bin
MZ
:\>
```